# Struct uint32 in java

Tags: java, struct, binary

I tried to read uint32 in Java. 
I do it well

```
byte[] record=new byte[4];
bBuff.get(record,0,4);
recordData = ((record[3] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((record[2] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((record[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (record[0] & 0xFF);
```

but this uint32 has special structure 
In documentation write

```
TTTR record, structured as follows (MSBit at the left):
Reserved[1], Valid[1], Route[2], Data[12], TimeTag[16]
If Valid==1
then Data = Channel
else Data = Overflow[1], Reserved[8], Marker[3]
```

In C code. It have structure of struct.

```
struct {
    unsigned TimeTag    :16;
    unsigned Channel    :12;
    unsigned Route      :2;
    unsigned Valid      :1;
    unsigned Reserved   :1; }  TTTRrecord;
```

What I did in java:

```
timeTag= recordData & 65535;
channel = (recordData>> 16) & 0x800;
route   = (recordData>> 28) & 2;
valid = (recordData>> 30) & 1;
reserved = (recordData>> 31) & 1;
```

But it looks like kind of magic. 
Everything works ok but not exactly. 
But I get 1 route instead of 2. 
It's like second route is off.
Maybe I have some problems with bit representation of route.

Comment: If you are getting 1 route instead of 2, how can you say "Everything works ok"?

Comment: I tried read C binary file in java. But have some problems with uin32 struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incorrect: bit masking for `Channel` and `Route` is off. It should look as follows:

```
timeTag  = (recordData >>  0) & 0xFFFF;
channel  = (recordData >> 16) & 0x0FFF;
route    = (recordData >> 28) & 0x0003;
valid    = (recordData >> 30) & 0x0001;
reserved = (recordData >> 31) & 0x0001;
```

"Magic number" on the right is called *bit mask*. It has `1`s in the bits that you would like to keep, and `0`s in the bits that you would like to clear.